# Check All Child Properties For Null in C#

Tags: c#, null

I have the following line of code below.  Is there a method that can check team, DivisionTeam, Team, Coordinator, Profile, Address, and the last property StateRegion for null instead of doing it for every property?

```
if(team.DivisionTeam.Team.Coordinator.Profile.Address.StateRegion != null)
```

Comment: you have to write your own method for this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2080647/deep-null-checking-is-there-a-better-way

Comment: [C# elegant way to check if a property's property is null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468250/c-sharp-elegant-way-to-check-if-a-propertys-property-is-null)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently in C#, you can't, you have to individually check each property for null.

May be you are looking for ".?" operator, but its not there in C# 4.0, Check out this post and the response from Eric Lippert: [Deep null checking, is there a better way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2080647/deep-null-checking-is-there-a-better-way)

Comment: Can you use reflection at all?

Comment: @MikeFlynn, I am not sure, how would you use reflection in this case ?

Answer (score 1):

You should check the following article: [Chained null checks and the Maybe monad](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/109026/Chained-null-checks-and-the-Maybe-monad). This is, IMO, the cleanest way to actually "do" what you are asking for.

And, no, there is no inbuilt way in C# to do this directly.

Answer (score 1):

In C# 6.0 you can do it in just one string:

`var something = team?.DivisionTeam?.Team?.Coordinator?.Profile?.Address?.StateRegion;`

Check this article for further reading: [null-conditional operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample

```
private bool IsValidTeam(Team team)
{ 
    bool result = false;
    if (team != null)
        if (team.DivisionTeam != null)
            if (team.DivisionTeam.Team != null)
                if (team.DivisionTeam.Team.Coordinator != null)
                    if (team.DivisionTeam.Team.Coordinator.Profile != null)
                        if (team.DivisionTeam.Team.Coordinator.Profile.Address != null)
                            if (team.DivisionTeam.Team.Coordinator.Profile.Address.StateRegion != null)
                                result = true;
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check my answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/34086283/4711853

You could simply write a small extension method, which afford you to write chained lambda like this:

```
var value = instance.DefaultOrValue(x => x.SecondInstance)
            .DefaultOrValue(x => x.ThirdInstance)
            .DefaultOrValue(x => x.Value);
```