# Is there such a thing as a chained NULL check?

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following ugly code:

```
if (msg == null || 
    msg.Content == null || 
    msg.Content.AccountMarketMessage == null || 
    msg.Content.AccountMarketMessage.Account == null ||
    msg.Content.AccountMarketMessage.Account.sObject == null) return;
```

Is there a way to chain check for null values in C#, so that I don't have to check each individual level?

Comment: Would be really nice, but no, there is not

Comment: possible duplicate of [Null coalescing operator override](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21051551/null-coalescing-operator-override). See [My Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21051617/643085) in that question.

Comment: I believe C#6 will let you do `if(msg.?Content.?AccountMarketMessage.?Account.?sObject == null) return;`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One of the [proposals in C# 6](http://roslyn.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Language%20Feature%20Status&referringTitle=Documentation) would be to add a new [Null Propagation operator](http://roslyn.codeplex.com/discussions/540883).

This will (hopefully) allow you to write:

```
var obj = msg?.Content?.AccountMarketMessage?.Account?.sObject;
if (obj == null) return;
```

Unfortunately, there is nothing in the language at this point that handles this.

Comment: I have thought about this for a while.. and I'm just not sure I like the syntax. Perhaps a double dot notation instead? `msg..Content..AccountMarketMessage..Account..sObject`. Mmm.. even that looks strange. Definitely looking forward to this though.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead The second link I pasted would be a good place for suggesting alternatives.

Comment: Question mark seems OK, as it bears quite well established "nullable" conotation.

Comment: @BartoszKP That is no doubt the reason it was chosen. It just doesn't feel natural to type `?.` next to each other (yet.. maybe it'll grow on me..).

Answer (score 4):

There is not currently such a thing, but it may be coming to .NET very soon.  There is [a well-known User Voice thread on the subject](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/3990187-add-operator-to-c).  And as noted in [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jerrynixon/archive/2014/02/26/at-last-c-is-getting-sometimes-called-the-safe-navigation-operator.aspx), the Visual Studio team has recently announced that:

> We are seriously considering this feature for C# and VB, and will be
>   prototyping it in coming months.

Edit: and as noted in [Reed Copsey's answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23231359/665376), it is now a planned addition for C# 6.  There are better details on the Codeplex pages he linked.

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in support for this, but you can use an extension method for that:

```
public static bool IsNull<T>(this T source, string path)
{
     var props = path.Split('.');
     var type = source.GetType();

     var currentObject = type.GetProperty(props[0]).GetValue(source);

     if (currentObject == null) return true;
     foreach (var prop in props.Skip(1))
     {
          currentObject = currentObject.GetType()
                .GetProperty(prop)
                .GetValue(currentObject);

         if (currentObject == null) return true;
     }

     return false;
}
```

Then call it:

```
if ( !msg.IsNull("Content.AccountMarketMessage.Account.sObject") )  return;
```

Comment: This works, but is very prone to error (magic strings) and has horrible performance...

Answer (score 2):

You need monads and Monadic null checking. Could have a look at [Monads.Net package](https://github.com/sergun/monads.net/wiki/Monads-for-objects). It can help with simplifying null tests and getting values from deep navigation properties

Something like

```
var sObject = person.With(p=>p.Content).With(w=>w.AccountMarketMessage ).With(p=>p.Account).With(p=>p.Object);
```

If you wanted a default value then

```
var sObject = person.With(p=>p.Content).With(w=>w.AccountMarketMessage).With(p=>p.Account).Return(p=>p.Object, "default value");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can lazily evaluate the values using lambda expressions. This is overkill for a simple null check, but can be useful for chaining more complex expressions in a "fluent" manner.

## Example

```
// a type that has many descendents
var nested = new Nested();

// setup an evaluation chain
var isNull =
    NullCheck.Check( () => nested )
        .ThenCheck( () => nested.Child )
        .ThenCheck( () => nested.Child.Child )
        .ThenCheck( () => nested.Child.Child.Child )
        .ThenCheck( () => nested.Child.Child.Child.Child );

// handle the results
Console.WriteLine( isNull.IsNull ? "null" : "not null" );
```

## Code

<sub>This is a full example (albeit draft-quality code) that can be pasted into a console app or LINQPad.</sub>

```
public class Nested
{
  public Nested Child
  {
      get;
      set;
  }
}

public class NullCheck
{
   public bool IsNull { get; private set; }

   // continues the chain
   public NullCheck ThenCheck( Func<object> test )
   {
       if( !IsNull )
       {
           // only evaluate if the last state was "not null"
           this.IsNull = test() == null;
       }

       return this;
   }

   // starts the chain (convenience method to avoid explicit instantiation)
   public static NullCheck Check( Func<object> test )
   {
       return new NullCheck { IsNull = test() == null };
   }
}

private void Main()
{
   // test 1
   var nested = new Nested();
   var isNull =
       NullCheck.Check( () => nested )
           .ThenCheck( () => nested.Child )
           .ThenCheck( () => nested.Child.Child )
           .ThenCheck( () => nested.Child.Child.Child )
           .ThenCheck( () => nested.Child.Child.Child.Child );

   Console.WriteLine( isNull.IsNull ? "null" : "not null" );

   // test 2
   nested = new Nested { Child = new Nested() };
   isNull = NullCheck.Check( () => nested ).ThenCheck( () => nested.Child );

   Console.WriteLine( isNull.IsNull ? "null" : "not null" );

   // test 3
   nested = new Nested { Child = new Nested() };
   isNull = NullCheck.Check( () => nested ).ThenCheck( () => nested.Child ).ThenCheck( () => nested.Child.Child );

   Console.WriteLine( isNull.IsNull ? "null" : "not null" );
}
```

Again: **you probably shouldn't use this in lieu of simple null checks due to the complexity it introduces**, but it's an interesting pattern.

Answer (score 0):

***[`.NET Fiddle`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vPY3MO)***

As stated there is a plan to have c# 6.0 implement the `?` operator to facilitate this process somewhat. If you cannot wait, I would suggest using a lambda expression and a simple helper function to solve this.

```
public E NestedProperty<T,E>(T Parent, Func<T,E> Path, E IfNullOrEmpty = default(E))
{
    try
    {
        return Path(Parent);
    }
    catch
    {
        return IfNullOrEmpty;
    }
}
```

This could be used `int value = NestedProperty<First,int>(blank,f => f.Second.Third.id);` as shown in the demo below

*program*

```
public class Program
{
    public void Main()
    {
        First blank = new First();
        First populated = new First(true);

        //where a value exists
        int value = NestedProperty<First,int>(blank,f => f.Second.Third.id);
        Console.WriteLine(value);//0

        //where no value exists
        value = NestedProperty<First,int>(populated,f => f.Second.Third.id);
        Console.WriteLine(value);//1

        //where no value exists and a default was used
        value = NestedProperty<First,int>(blank,f => f.Second.Third.id,-1);
        Console.WriteLine(value);//-1
    }

    public E NestedProperty<T,E>(T Parent, Func<T,E> Path, E IfNullOrEmpty = default(E))
    {
        try
        {
            return Path(Parent);
        }
        catch
        {
            return IfNullOrEmpty;
        }
    }
}
```

*simple demo structure*

```
public class First
{
    public Second Second { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public First(){}
    public First(bool init)
    {
        this.id = 1;
        this.Second = new Second();
    }
}

public class Second
{
    public Third Third { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public Second()
    {
        this.id = 1;
        this.Third = new Third();
    }
}

public class Third
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public Third()
    {
        this.id = 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since 3.5 (maybe earlier), You could write very simple extension method

```
  public static TResult DefaultOrValue<T, TResult> (this T source, 
                                                Func<T, TResult> property) where T : class
    {
        return source == null ? default(TResult) : property(source);
    }
```

You may name this method even shortier and then use like this

```
 var instance = new First {SecondInstance = new Second 
                          {ThirdInstance = new Third {Value = 5}}};
        var val =
            instance .DefaultOrValue(x => x.SecondInstance)
                .DefaultOrValue(x => x.ThirdInstance)
                .DefaultOrValue(x => x.Value);
        Console.WriteLine(val);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

so source classes are:

```
public class Third
{
    public int Value;
}

public class First
{
    public Second SecondInstance;
}

public class Second
{
    public Third ThirdInstance;
}
```