# MVC how to check for NULL in model.property

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

In a razor-view, how can I check the existence of a property in a model?

```
if (Model._myProp != null)  <--- error .RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException if Model does not contain _myProp
    {
      ...do something
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468250/c-sharp-elegant-way-to-check-if-a-propertys-property-is-null

Comment: Please, stop referring to "ASP.NET MVC" simply as "MVC". One is a framework, while other is a language-independent design pattern. It's like calling IE - "the internet"

Answer (score 1):

You do not want to check that one of the model's properties has the value null you want to check the type for it is having a property or not and ofcourse you solution will not work that way but @Satpal's wont work too.

Use stronly typed views and separate different properties into interfaces and use them with partial views.