# C# elegant way to check if all shallow properties are null (or any property is not null)

Tags: c#

This concern comes up when I read this
[Deep Null checking, is there a better way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2080647/deep-null-checking-is-there-a-better-way)

and this

[C# elegant way to check if a property's property is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468250/c-sharp-elegant-way-to-check-if-a-propertys-property-is-null)

**Say I want to check if all properties are NOT null or there is any property is NOT null.** (shallow properties)

**SearchCriteria object:**

```
Keyword (Searches Name and Description) != null ||
SectorId != null ||
IndustryId != null ||
HasOption != null ||
HasFutures != null ||
30 properties to go...
```

As we can see, the syntax is somehow hard to read. And I want something like

```
SearchCriteria
.Has(criteria => criteria.Keywork)
.Has(criteria => criteria.SectorId)
.Has(criteria => criteria.HasOption)
.etc
```

(in case we want all above properties are NOT null)

OR

```
SearchCriteria
.Has(criteria => criteria.Keywork).Or()
.Has(criteria => criteria.SectorId).Or()
.Has(criteria => criteria.HasOption).Or()
.etc
```

(In case we want any property is NOT null)

OR

```
SearchCriteria
.Has(criteria => criteria.Keywork).Or()
.Has(criteria => criteria.SectorId)
.Has(criteria => criteria.HasOption)
.etc
```

(In case we want Keyword **or** SectorId has value **and** HasOption has value.

So do we have any existed project on codeplex for this? Or any elegant approach that can combine both **deep null checking and shallow null checking**?

Comment: If it was a blittable `struct` you could check the memory is zeroed, though I'm not sure that counts as "elegant"; it's removed enough from the C# to count as much more ugly than what you have.

Comment: @JonHanna it also depends on whether a field like `int foo` with value `0` should could as `null` or not

Comment: I advise you to read this... http://blogs.encodo.ch/news/view_article.php?id=167 Elegant Code vs Clean Code "Cleverness is wonderful, but you may end up severely limiting the number of people willing—or able—to work on that code."

Comment: @MarcGravell you could examine the appropriate subset of the octets in question, but that only increases said ugliness.

Comment: @PaulZahra: 1 vote for the article, it is very helpful. Sometime semantics of code is not what we need.

Comment: @VuNguyen Indeed, I'm supporting a website made by two developers with a PHD each, one went on to work for Microsoft and another to Google... the code they developed, while often clever and sometimes efficient, is often a bloody nightmare to maintain / develop.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Frankly, I'd stick with the simple version involving `||` or `&&`, `== null` or `!= null`. It it direct and efficient, and allows immediate short-circuiting. If you are going to be doing this *lots*, you could perhaps write a utility class that uses meta-programming (`Expression` or `ILGenerator` maybe) to create an optimized method once per-type that checks all the properties, then:

```
if(MyHelper.AllNull(obj)) ... // note this is probably actually generic
```

Full example:

```
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Reflection;

static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        bool x = MyHelper.AnyNull(new Foo { }); // true
        bool y = MyHelper.AnyNull(new Foo { X = "" }); // false
    }
}
class Foo
{
    public string X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
}
static class MyHelper
{
    public static bool AnyNull<T>(T obj)
    {
        return Cache<T>.AnyNull(obj);
    }
    static class Cache<T>
    {
        public static readonly Func<T, bool> AnyNull;

        static Cache()
        {
            var props = typeof(T).GetProperties(
                BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);

            var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "obj");
            Expression body = null;

            foreach(var prop in props)
            {
                if (!prop.CanRead) continue;

                if(prop.PropertyType.IsValueType)
                {
                    Type underlyingType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(
                                              prop.PropertyType);
                    if (underlyingType == null) continue; // cannot be null

                    // TODO: handle Nullable<T>
                }
                else
                {
                    Expression check = Expression.Equal(
                        Expression.Property(param, prop),
                        Expression.Constant(null, prop.PropertyType));
                    body = body == null ? check : Expression.OrElse(body, check);
                }
            }
            if (body == null) AnyNull = x => false; // or true?
            else
            {
                AnyNull = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, param).Compile();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I wonder if this could sometimes be one of the cases where using `|` and `&` would be actually more efficient than `||` and `&&` because the gain from avoiding branching can beat the gain from short-circuting. The short-circuiting approach would be the one to do by default before profiling showed otherwise as it's the more efficient 99% of the time, but it's interesting to consider.

Comment: @MarcGravell: I'm interested with your answer. However, I prefer check only the specified properties with more flexible syntax as the last pseudo-code above. And I do agree with "It it direct and efficient, and allows immediate short-circuiting."

Answer (score 2):

Although I do support Marc Gravell's answer to simply write it out fully, if you do insist on not repeating the `!= null`, you do not need to create any custom methods. LINQ methods can already do what you want, for example like so:

```
new[] { SearchCriteria }.SelectMany(criteria => new object[] {
  criteria.Keywork,
  criteria.SectorId,
  criteria.HasOption,
  ...
}).Any(p => p != null)
```

To also cover the case where `SearchCriteria` itself might be `null`, you can use

```
new[] { SearchCriteria }.Where(criteria => criteria != null).SelectMany(...
```

Comment: That's a lot of allocations for a simple check... and it relies on you remembering to maintain the code in multiple places

Comment: @MarcGravell Agreed with the lots of allocations, but the way I'm reading the question, the OP isn't necessarily interested in checking *all* properties, but only the specified properties. The OP's suggested syntax also writes out the properties explicitly.