# Is there a way to return null instead of throwing a NullReferenceException?

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception, nullable

I have the following C# problem.

Consider the function:

```cs
private String getStringFromNullabel()
{
    var nullable = getClass();  // returns some object that could be null
    if( nullable != null)
    {
         return nullable.Text;
    }
    return null;
}
```

This works but it is verbose and I would rather write something like:

```cs
private String getStringFromNullabel()
{
    return NotThrowWrapper(getClass()).Text; 
}
```

This will throw if getClass() returns null.
So I am looking for some syntax that is short enough that this stays a one-liner but rather returns null instead of throwing an exception.

Is there such a thing in C#?

Comment: `if( nullable != 0)` is not the way how you check for `null`.

Comment: C# 6 has syntax for this, did you try searching?

Comment: Search for Null Propagation Operator in C# 6

Comment: what type does `getClass` return?

Comment: if you want the code to fit in one line, you could use the ternary operator

Comment: @Tim: I am a C# beginner. What would be correct?

Comment: @Knitschi: `if( nullable != null)`

Comment: Try http://mattdufeu.co.uk/null-conditional-operators-in-c-6/

Comment: @CodeCaster: I was not sure what to search for, but "null instead of NullReferenceException" did not turn up much in the first pages. I am stuck with C# 5 so you say we have no solution here.

Comment: @Knitschi correct, but like S.Dav said you could change it to `return nullable != null ? nullable.Text : null;`

Comment: @Knitschi see [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468250/c-sharp-elegant-way-to-check-if-a-propertys-property-is-null), first hit on "C# prevent null checks".

Comment: @CodeCaster: I guess I used the wrong search words.

Comment: @Knitschi no problem, hope the duplicate helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pre C#6

```
private String GetStringFromNullabel()
{
 var nullable = getClass();  // returns some object that could be null
 return nullable  != null ? nullable .Text : null;
}
```

Post C# 6

```
private String GetStringFromNullabel()
{
 return getClass()?.Text;
}
```

Note that you should follow the .NET [naming conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: With C#6 the whole method `GetStringFromNullabel` is pretty redundant.

Comment: Agreed.  In c#6 "getStringFromNullabel" is called "?".  Plus it has a spelling mistake... :)