# VB equiv - Elegant way to check if a property's property is null

Tags: vb.net, equivalent, null-check

I noticed this great post on how to do inline null checks on nested objects/properties: [C# elegant way to check if a property's property is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468250/c-sharp-elegant-way-to-check-if-a-propertys-property-is-null)

Is there a VB.NET equivalent available?

Comment: its [just the same](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36698516/1132334)

Comment: if using the latest version yes. same as c#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The null-conditional operator ([MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators)) also exists in VB.NET (VB 14 and above, i.e., Visual Studio 2015 and above) and has the same syntax:

```
Dim value As Int32? = objectA?.PropertyA?.PropertyB?.PropertyC
```

Often, this is combined with the null-coalescing operator, which is `a ?? b` in C# and `If(a, b)` in VB.NET:

```
Dim value As Int32 = If(objectA?.PropertyA?.PropertyB?.PropertyC, 0)  ' Default value if null
```