# Null check on a property error

Tags: c#

I have a simple null check on a property getting but for some reason it won't compile.

This is how it looks

```
    private TestObj _someObj;
    public bool IsActive
    {
        get { return _someObj?.IsActive; }
    }
```

I thought the `?` would return false if `_someObj` was null ? Have i misunderstood its use here?

The error i get:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type `bool?' to `bool'
```

I tried adding an if statement around it but same problem occurred.

Hope you can help explain my misunderstanding.

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468250/c-sharp-elegant-way-to-check-if-a-propertys-property-is-null?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: `_someObj?.IsActive` is nullable. so you will need to add a condition that possibility `_someObj?.IsActive ?? false`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_someObj?.IsActive` is a nullable condition, so assuming `IsActive` is of type `bool`, using `?.` will turn the result to a nullable bool `bool?/Nullable<bool>` which will conflict with the expected `bool` result of the property.

If `_someObj` is *null* then the result will also be *null*, so you will need to add a [null-coalescing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operator) for that possibility

```
public bool IsActive {
    get { return _someObj?.IsActive ?? false; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `_someObj` is null, it has to return `null`, but if it's `true` or `false` it has to return that, therefore it returns a `bool?` which can be `true`, `false`, or `null`.

There are two ways to fix this. You can do:

```
public bool IsActive => _someObject ?? false;
```

The above is exactly the same as doing:

```
public bool IsActive => _someObejct != null ? _someObject : false;
```

It's going to return false if `_someObject` is null. Another solution is to change the type of `IsActive` to be a `bool?`, like this:

```
public bool? IsActive => _someObject;
```

And you don't have to use any null checking, only in that one instance. You will have to check if it is null everytime you want to use `IsActive`, which is properly not ideal.