# Is there a way to extract contents of a JSON string using LINQ

Tags: c#, json, linq

I have this code:

```
var jsonResponse = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            List<TranslationResult> a  = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject< List<TranslationResult>>(jsonResponse);
var t0 = (a[0] != null) ? a[0] : null;
var t1 = (t0 != null) ? t0.Translations[0] : null;
var t2 = (t1 != null) ? t1.DisplayTarget : null;
var p2 = (t1 != null) ? t1.PosTag : null;

public class TranslationResult
{
    public string DisplaySource { get; set; }
    public Translation[] Translations { get; set; }
}

public class Translation
{
    public string DisplayTarget { get; set; }
    public string PosTag { get; set; }
}
```

The code I am using with all the null tests looks messy and I would like to clean this up.  Can anyone suggest a way that I can do this or perhaps suggest a way using LINQ if that's possible. Note that I only need the DisplayTarget and PosTag details.

Comment: Not related to your question, but please see https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html regarding the `.ReadAsStringAsync().Result`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# elegant way to check if a property's property is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468250/c-sharp-elegant-way-to-check-if-a-propertys-property-is-null)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only use LINQ to get the translation results and translations within. You will still have to unpack `DisplayTarget` and `PosTag`.

```
List<TranslationResult> a = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TranslationResult>>(jsonResponse);
var firstTranslation = a.FirstOrDefault()?.Translations?.FirstOrDefault();
var displayTarget = firstTranslation?.DisplayTarget;
var posTag = firstTranslation?.PosTag;
```

Also, you could use C# 7.0 tuples to unpack multiple values in one go.

```
List<TranslationResult> a = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TranslationResult>>(jsonResponse);
var firstTranslation = a.FirstOrDefault()?.Translations?.FirstOrDefault();
var (displayTarget, posTag) = (firstTranslation?.DisplayTarget, firstTranslation?.PosTag);
```

If you would like to use all the values, not just first like in your example, you can use LINQ as following:

```cs
List<TranslationResult> results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TranslationResult>>(jsonResponse);
var translations = (results ?? Enumerable.Empty<TranslationResult>())
            .Select(x => x.Translations)
            .Where(x => x != null)
            .SelectMany(x => x)
            .Where(x => x != null)
            .Select(x => (x.DisplayTarget, x.PosTag));
foreach (var (displayTarget, posTag) in translations)
{
    // do something with displayTarget and posTag
}
```

Comment: This only returns 1 result from a list with n results and discards the remaining n-1 results for both collections (inner and outer).

Comment: @BionicCode Thanks! Expanded on it. Got confused by the question, to me, it seemed like only the first value is needed.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example using Linq and named tuples:

```
List<TranslationResult> a = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TranslationResult>>(jsonResponse);

IEnumerable<(string DisplayTarget, string PosTag)> tuples = 
  a.Where(t0 => t0?.Translations ?? false)
    .SelectMany(
      t0 => t0.Translations.Select(
        t1 => (DisplayTarget: t1?.DisplayTarget ?? string.Empty, PosTag: t1?.PosTag ?? string.Empty)));

// Iterate over the result of named tuples
foreach ((string DisplayTarget, string PosTag) tuple : tuples)
{
  // Values are string.Empty when they returned null from deserialization
  var displayTarget = tuple.DisplayTarget;
  var posTag = tuple.PosTag;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var t0 = (a[0] != null) ? a[0] : null;
```

This can be changed to

```
var t0 = a[0];
```

because the result is the same. And

```
var t1 = (t0 != null) ? t0.Translations[0] : null;
var t2 = (t1 != null) ? t1.DisplayTarget : null;
var p2 = (t1 != null) ? t1.PosTag : null;
```

can be changed to

```
var t1 = t0?.Translations[0];
var t2 = t1?.DisplayTarget;
var p2 = t1?.PosTag;
```

Using the [null condition operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-) is a short form for the "if not null return this otherwise return null" check.

Answer (score 1):

Might be easier to [query](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SelectToken.htm) it :

```
 string PosTag = (string)JToken.Parse(jsonResponse).SelectToken("$..PosTag");
```