# Html Agility Pack gives NullReferenceException for items that exist

Tags: c#, .net-core, html-agility-pack, nullreferenceexception

I'm getting started with [Html Agility Pack](https://html-agility-pack.net) but I'm struggling with it throwing a `NullReferenceException` for items I know for a fact exists.

For example, take this code:

```
doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("div").ToList()[2]
```

This returns a valid `HtmlNode` on which I can do `node.Attributes["id"]` and get the value of the `id` attribute ("somevalue" in this case).

However, if I try to get this specific element based on the attribute value I get a `NullReferenceException`:

```
doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("div").FirstOrDefault(e => e.Attributes["id"].Value == "somevalue")
```

Why does this code throw a `NullReferenceException` when an element with this attribute and this value actually exist?

Comment: Can you provide the xml file?

Comment: Because there's at least one descendant `div` that does not have an id attribute.

Comment: @HereticMonkey That could definitely explain it. How can you select a child node based on an attribute value where not all children are guaranteed to have this attribute?

Comment: Check if the attribute exists first. I don't know Html Agility Pack, but you could do `e => e.Attributes["id"]?.Value == "somevalue"`, using the [safe navigation operator](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jerrynixon/2014/02/26/at-last-c-is-getting-sometimes-called-the-safe-navigation-operator/) (a.k.a. null-conditional operator) to make sure it is found. See [C# elegant way to check if a property's property is null](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3468250/215552)

Comment: The xpath query can be `//div/@id[not(.="")]`

Comment: @HereticMonkey The null-conditional operator did the trick. Thanks! :)